# Getting distance between route and points around that route?

Tags: openlayers, openstreetmap, open-source-routing-machine

I have a route between 2 points by means of OSM routing service.

[image: output_of_routing]

I want to get the distance between route and points around. How can I achieve this?

I created this route by the following example https://jsfiddle.net/jonataswalker/079xha47/:

```
var points = [],
    msg_el = document.getElementById('msg'),
    url_osrm_nearest = '//router.project-osrm.org/nearest/v1/driving/',
    url_osrm_route = '//router.project-osrm.org/route/v1/driving/',
    icon_url = '//cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/ol3/master/examples/data/icon.png',
    vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector(),
    vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
      source: vectorSource
    }),
    styles = {
      route: new ol.style.Style({
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
          width: 6, color: [40, 40, 40, 0.8]
        })
      }),
      icon: new ol.style.Style({
        image: new ol.style.Icon({
          anchor: [0.5, 1],
          src: icon_url
        })
      })
    };

console.clear();

var map = new ol.Map({
  target: 'map',
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.OSM()
    }),
    vectorLayer
  ],
  view: new ol.View({
    center: [-5685003, -3504484],
    zoom: 11
  })
});

map.on('click', function(evt){
  utils.getNearest(evt.coordinate).then(function(coord_street){
    var last_point = points[points.length - 1];
    var points_length = points.push(coord_street);

    utils.createFeature(coord_street);

    if (points_length < 2) {
      msg_el.innerHTML = 'Click to add another point';
      return;
    }

    //get the route
    var point1 = last_point.join();
    var point2 = coord_street.join();

    fetch(url_osrm_route + point1 + ';' + point2).then(function(r) { 
      return r.json();
    }).then(function(json) {
      if(json.code !== 'Ok') {
        msg_el.innerHTML = 'No route found.';
        return;
      }
      msg_el.innerHTML = 'Route added';
      //points.length = 0;
      utils.createRoute(json.routes[0].geometry);
    });
  });
});

var utils = {
  getNearest: function(coord){
    var coord4326 = utils.to4326(coord);    
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      //make sure the coord is on street
      fetch(url_osrm_nearest + coord4326.join()).then(function(response) { 
        // Convert to JSON
        return response.json();
      }).then(function(json) {
        if (json.code === 'Ok') resolve(json.waypoints[0].location);
        else reject();
      });
    });
  },
  createFeature: function(coord) {
    var feature = new ol.Feature({
      type: 'place',
      geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.fromLonLat(coord))
    });
    feature.setStyle(styles.icon);
    vectorSource.addFeature(feature);
  },
  createRoute: function(polyline) {
    // route is ol.geom.LineString
    var route = new ol.format.Polyline({
      factor: 1e5
    }).readGeometry(polyline, {
      dataProjection: 'EPSG:4326',
      featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857'
    });
    var feature = new ol.Feature({
      type: 'route',
      geometry: route
    });
    feature.setStyle(styles.route);
    vectorSource.addFeature(feature);
  },
  to4326: function(coord) {
    return ol.proj.transform([
      parseFloat(coord[0]), parseFloat(coord[1])
    ], 'EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:4326');
  }
};
```

Comment: The shortest distance from point to polygon (route) or to polygon point?

Comment: from route to point is better.

Comment: I've made an update to your fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/8g3dkyxL/2/  After creating the route any further clicks add points and use getClosestPoint to find the closest point on the route.  Then you can use spherical geometry to calculate the length of the line between the points.  I've updated to OpenLayers 4 as the old version you were using didn't support that.